# Slow performing PostgreSQL Query, not understood why

Tags: database, performance, postgresql

I have the following query in rails which uses PostgreSQL 9 as the DB.

```
@user_random = User.where(:id => User.where(:pubic_profile_visible => true).order('random()').limit(1).select(:id).collect(&:id)).first
```

Which then on the DB Server:

**Explain plan**

```
Query plan  Limit  (cost=48655.53..48655.53 rows=1 width=4)
Query plan    ->  Sort  (cost=48655.53..50880.35 rows=889930 width=4)
Query plan          Sort Key: (random())
Query plan          ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..44205.88 rows=889930 width=4)
Query plan                Filter: (pubic_profile_visible AND (deleted_at IS NULL))
```

Any suggestions on why this is causing a bottleneck? Thank you

Comment: Well, it appears you are sorting 800K records on random(), to pick only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @wildplasser says this query is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

It can't pick the lowest random() for your "LIMIT 1" without fetching all 800,000 rows, generating a random number and then sorting them.

Try googling "postgresql select random row" and you'll get half a dozen useful stackoverflow questions and also a link to an old blog post on depesz.com which covers the various options:

http://www.depesz.com/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/

Comment: Note that in 9.5 you can now use TABLESAMPLE in the FROM clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM and http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/